# Ventanas de alert de JS se muestran infinitamente

Tags: javascript

Poseo varios ficheros JS que validan campos, ocurre que al cumplirse la condicion hacen el alert y luego se vuelve a cumplir y sigue asi hasta que marcas "Evitar que esta pagina..."

Como lo soluciono?

Ejemplo obtener llamado con ONBLUR

```
function obtener() {
var ejemplo= { xvalor: $('#valor').val() }
$.post("unarchivo.php", xvalor , function( respuesta ) {
if(respuesta.a==99999 )
{
        alert("No existe");
        $('#ejemplo').val("");

}
else
{

    $('#a').val(respuesta.a);
    $('#b').val(respuesta.b);
    $('#c').val(respuesta.c)
}   
}, "json" );
```

Crei que uno de los problemas era hacer el FOCUS al valor y lo quite pero persiste.

O tal vez que al meter mal el valor y salirte(blur) te pone la caja vacia y como vacio no existe en la base de datos te da error y hace un bucle?

Que puedo hacer para que solo muestre el valor y no persista

HTML:

```
<script src="funciones/obtener.js"></script>

<tr>
   <td>Cedula: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input type="text" name="ccedula" id="ccedula" onblur="obtenerSancionado()" maxlength="10" size="12"></td>
   </td>
   </tr>
```

PHP:

el php si no consigue el valor, pasa como respuesta que a=9999
Por eso luego se cumple la primera condicion

```
 if ($stmt->num_rows === 0)
    {
    $datos = json_encode(array(
      "a" => '99999'
    ));
    echo $datos;
    }
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55278/discussion-on-question-by-victor-a-ventanas-de-alert-de-js-se-muestran-infinita).

Comment: @Víctor_Random: ¿Encontraste la solución?

Comment: Hola, si jejeje pero no la había publicado,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue cambiar al evento `onchange`. Ya que no recuerdo el nombre de la persona que me dijo (si te acuerdas dime y modificó la respuesta) chrome estaba dando problemas con ese evento en su versión actual.

Ocurre que tanto salir del foco de la caja de texto como el mensaje que sale al escribir mal la cédula o no escribirla, accionan el evento `onblur`, por eso se repetía infinitamente, entraba no había dato y mostraba mensaje luego al aceptar se repetía el ciclo.